# Angular 7 Test: NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

Hi have some error with testing my App made with Angular 7. I do not have much experience in angular, so I would need your help+

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BeerDetailsComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BeerDetailsComponent -> ActivatedRoute]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
```

the testing code is like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BeerDetailsComponent } from './beer-details.component';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('BeerDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: BeerDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BeerDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ BeerDetailsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BeerDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create',
  inject(
    [HttpTestingController],
    () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    }
  )
)
});
```

I really can't find any solution.

Daniele

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Add the following import

```
  imports: [ 
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ...
  ],
```

Comment: where should i import RouterModule.forRoot([]),?

Comment: In the module `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: RouterModule should not be included in the test files

Comment: thats not a proper solution, by this you need to define all roter module provider params, APP_BASE_HREF token etc. Use instead  RouterTestingModule with no router provider declarations

Comment: Would be a good answer if you stated where the import should be added

Comment: @daniele-caputo, make sure that you have accepted the currect answer. 
other answers with import: [RouterTestingModule] resolved my error.

Comment: The correct answer is provided by @prathvi-shetty below.

Answer (score 148):

You have to import RouterTestingModule

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";

imports: [
    ...
    RouterTestingModule
    ...
]
```

Comment: When I do this, I start getting the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!`

Comment: Did you imported this module into the spec file?

Comment: I believe the solution was to add a provider for the route, using an anonymous object containing the properties accessed by the test.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: If you are coming to this in 2022 then `RouterTestingModule` now lives in `@angular/common/http/testing`

Comment: @MikePoole I just used the  `RouterTestingModule` in Angular 17, and it still lives on `@angular/router/testing` and not `@angular/common/http/testing`

Comment: @desoga It does still exist there, but it is marked as deprecated.

Comment: @Domin Doesn't deprecation means it will be dropped in a matter of time, and could possibly cause compilation error?

Comment: [RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) is deprecated. Use `provideRouter` or `RouterModule.forRoot` instead.

Answer (score 31):

I had this error for some time as well while testing, and none of these answers really helped me. What fixed it for me was importing both the RouterTestingModule and the HttpClientTestingModule.

**So essentially it would look like this in your whatever.component.spec.ts file.**

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

You can get the imports from

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
```

I dont know if this is the best solution, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

This issue can be fixed as follows:

1. In your corresponding **spec.ts** file import RouterTestingModule

   `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';`
2. In the same file add **RouterTestingModule** as one of the imports

   ```
    beforeEach(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [RouterTestingModule],
       providers: [Service]
     });
    });
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Example of a simple test using the service and ActivatedRoute! Good luck!

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { MyService } from '../../core/services/my.service';


    describe('MyComponent class test', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let teste: MyComponent;
    let route: ActivatedRoute;
    let myService: MyService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        teste = new MyComponent(route, myService);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ MyComponent ],
        imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            HttpClientModule
        ],
        providers: [MyService]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('Checks if the class was created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    });
```

Comment: Are you using `teste` anywhere? for what is it needed?

Comment: I use everywhere I work, a way to ensure that the application keeps working after some change without breaking my code.

Answer (score 0):

[RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) is deprecated. Use `providerRouter` or `RouterModule.forRoot` instead. The accepted answer uses `RouterModule.forRoot`. If you want to use `providerRouter` instead, add `providers: [provideRouter([])]` below `imports`

```
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ AppComponent ],
      providers: [provideRouter([])],
    }).compileComponents();
  }
```